# oracle query with analytic function to set row number with condition wise

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello I have wrote a query which get vehicle data by row number with some action in and out. I a have wrote a condition if action equal to "IN" then row number for in show in different column and for "OUT" row number out  show in diffrent column with partition by passnumber.
But I want to reset the row number if condition meet "OUT" for same passnumber here is the fiddle for the query http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7e0d9/1 and here is the code

```
  SELECT
  agent_id,
  passnumber,





                case
                when action='IN' then
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                    PARTITION BY passnumber
                    ORDER BY
                        passnumber ASC
                ) 
                end AS rn_in,
                case
                when action='OUT' then
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                    PARTITION BY passnumber
                    ORDER BY
                        passnumber ASC
                ) 
                end AS rn_out
            FROM
            vehicle_log
```

the result I am getting like this

```
      agent_id   passnumber   rn_in  rn_out
      ========   ==========   =====  ======

      1          1214         1      null
      1          1214         2      null
      1          1214         null   3
```

but I am expected like this

```
      agent_id   passnumber   rn_in  rn_out
      ========   ==========   =====  ======

      1          1214         1      null
      1          1214         2      null
      1          1214         null   1
```

can you please tell me how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `Action` in `PARTITION`

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7e0d9/16)**

```
SELECT agent_id,passnumber,
       case when action='IN' then ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY passnumber,action ORDER BY passnumber ASC) 
       end AS rn_in,
       case when action='OUT' then ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY passnumber,action ORDER BY passnumber ASC) 
       end AS rn_out
FROM vehicle_log
```

Answer (score 1):

You must add Action column to your partition case.
You can try this code:

```
SELECT
agent_id,
passnumber,
case when action='IN' then
                    row_number() OVER(
                        PARTITION BY passnumber,action
                        ORDER BY
                            passnumber,action ASC
                    ) 
                    end AS rn_in,   case
                    when action='OUT' then
                    row_number() OVER(
                        PARTITION BY passnumber,action
                        ORDER BY
                            passnumber,action ASC
                    ) 
                    end AS rn_out
                FROM
                vehicle_log
```

Comment: why you added action actin at order by?

Comment: adding order by does not change anything, because action values is same for all rn_in or rn_out. So it depends your choice. the output does not change. The point is adding action  to partition.